# DIV with background image?

Tags: html, dhtml

I have 2 DIVs and I want them replaced like Horizontal scroll Any div have a different image
How can i do it

I want to display 3 products move from right to left. I want to put a background of a picture, excuse the language I'm new on the road, 
Thanks  in advance

Comment: It's a little hard understanding your question.

Comment: Please be more specific. What you have tried that didn't work could help a lot, for instance.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow, mnaftal! It is clear you have a question, but please spend some time in stating the problem properly, including example code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you want, but near as I can tell, you want to change the background image of a DIV.

This is relatively easy to do with jQuery:

```
$('#the_div').css('backgroundImage','url("new_image.png")');
```

Take a look at the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamicly change the background of the div, then I suggest you go with George Edison's solution. You will have to use Javascript at some point and jQuery is just a sweet library for Javascript.

If, however, you want the images to be static and you want them all in one div, you can use [CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/backgrounds.html) to achieve this.